# Join with JSON fields

Tags: json, postgresql

In the database (postgres 10) i work with at the moment i have a lot of columns with json format strings (text fields)

I have a hard time to search,filter and join with values inside thoose strings.

I created an example in fiddle and i hope someone can help me solve it.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d003c1cea832e35696260b10c6b4c047

Here is my two problems i found tricky.

1. In table object -> configuration field i have "date_kg_later" field. It could be [] or hold more dates. In my select i want to get the highest date if it's not empty.
2. In table object -> object_type_cd refers on a value inside the records string in code_table. Here i want to get the title from that string back.

My goal is an output like this:

```
id    name        object_type_name    date
1000  Headphones  tech                2022-04-30
1001  Pencil      null                null
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first question : if the json structure of your configuration field conforms the example you provide, then a solution can be :

Before Postgres 12 :

```
SELECT Max((c.elt->>'date_from') :: date)
  FROM object
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements(configuration->'date_kg_later') AS c(elt)
 GROUP BY your_object_table_key
```

From and after Postgres 12 :

```
SELECT Max(d :: text :: date)
  FROM object
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements((configuration :: jsonb)->'date_kg_later', '$[*].date_from') AS d
 GROUP BY your_object_table_key
```

Your second question is unclear to me, needs more explanation.

Comment: jsonb_path_query doens't exist in postgres 10.8 :(